# How to make sure the game isnt running faster on other computers?

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe, frame-rate

I am making a game, and right now I am just tinkering around with image drawing, key input, etc. Right now all I have is a Pikachu moving around with the arrow keys (The game has nothing to do with Pokemon, Pikachu is just the image I chose) and I would like to make sure that the game does not run faster on other computers because of software capabilities (As in Pikachu would go from point A to point B faster than another computer, rather than it just lagging a little bit like other games)

I believe I'm doing it right, as I heard not to tie the engine to the frame, and the Only thing the frame is doing is displaying its X, Y, etc. everything else is done outside of the frame.

Here is my code:

```
package net.trenterprises;

import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main implements KeyListener {

static JLabel LabelImage = null;
static ArrayList<String> KeysPressed = new ArrayList<String>();
static int UP = 38;
static int DOWN = 40;
static int LEFT = 37;
static int RIGHT = 39;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Window TestWindow = new Window("Mouse Location", null);
    KeyListener listener = new Main();
    TestWindow.addKeyListener(listener);
    TestWindow.setLayout(null);
    int MouseX = 0;
    int MouseY = 0;
    JLabel MouseLabel = new JLabel("???");
    MouseLabel.setSize(MouseLabel.getPreferredSize());
    TestWindow.add(MouseLabel);
    try {
        BufferedImage CUPCAKES = (ImageIO.read(new URL("http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140328192412/pokemon/images/thumb/0/0d/025Pikachu.png/200px-025Pikachu.png")));
        LabelImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(CUPCAKES));
        TestWindow.add(LabelImage);
        LabelImage.setSize(LabelImage.getPreferredSize());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LabelImage.setBounds(0, 0, LabelImage.getSize().width, LabelImage.getSize().height);
    new PikaMoveUp().start();
    new PikaMoveDown().start();
    new PikaMoveLeft().start();
    new PikaMoveRight().start();
    while(true) {
        MouseX = (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x);
        MouseY = (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y);
        MouseLabel.setText("Mouse X: " + MouseX + "\n Mouse Y: " + MouseY);
        MouseLabel.setSize(MouseLabel.getPreferredSize());
        MouseLabel.setBounds(0, 0, MouseLabel.getSize().width, MouseLabel.getSize().height);
    }
}

public static int getPikaX() {
    return LabelImage.getX();
}

public static int getPikaY() {
    return LabelImage.getY();
}

public static void setPikachuPosition(int x, int y) {
    LabelImage.setBounds(x, y, LabelImage.getSize().width, LabelImage.getSize().height);
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int Char = (int) e.getKeyChar();
    int Keycode = (int) e.getKeyCode();
    if(Char == 65535) {
        if(Keycode == UP) {
            if(!KeysPressed.contains(Keycode + "")) {
                KeysPressed.add(Keycode + "");
            }
        }
        if(Keycode == DOWN) {
            if(!KeysPressed.contains(Keycode + "")) {
                KeysPressed.add(Keycode + "");
            }
        }
        if(Keycode == LEFT) {
            if(!KeysPressed.contains(Keycode + "")) {
                KeysPressed.add(Keycode + "");
            }
        }
        if(Keycode == RIGHT) {
            if(!KeysPressed.contains(Keycode + "")) {
                KeysPressed.add(Keycode + "");
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int Char = (int) e.getKeyChar();
    int Keycode = (int) e.getKeyCode();
    if(Char == 65535) {
        if(Keycode == UP) {
            while(KeysPressed.contains(Keycode + "")) {
                KeysPressed.remove(Keycode + "");
            }
        }
        if(Keycode == DOWN) {
            while(KeysPressed.contains(Keycode + "")) {
                KeysPressed.remove(Keycode + "");
            }
        }
        if(Keycode == LEFT) {
            while(KeysPressed.contains(Keycode + "")) {
                KeysPressed.remove(Keycode + "");
            }
        }
        if(Keycode == RIGHT) {
            while(KeysPressed.contains(Keycode + "")) {
                KeysPressed.remove(Keycode + "");
            }
        }
    }
}

class PikaMoveUp extends Thread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                while(Main.KeysPressed.contains(Main.UP + "")) {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                    Main.setPikachuPosition(Main.getPikaX(), Main.getPikaY() - 1);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception E) {
                E.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class PikaMoveDown extends Thread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                while(Main.KeysPressed.contains(Main.DOWN + "")) {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                    Main.setPikachuPosition(Main.getPikaX(), Main.getPikaY() + 1);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception E) {
                E.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class PikaMoveLeft extends Thread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                while(Main.KeysPressed.contains(Main.LEFT + "")) {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                    Main.setPikachuPosition(Main.getPikaX() - 1, Main.getPikaY());
                }
            }
            catch(Exception E) {
                E.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class PikaMoveRight extends Thread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                while(Main.KeysPressed.contains(Main.RIGHT + "")) {
                Thread.sleep(5);
                Main.setPikachuPosition(Main.getPikaX() + 1, Main.getPikaY());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception E) {
            E.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using threads *at all* then you will get unpredictable timings on different computers.

Comment: Ok, why is it that? I would like to know :)

Comment: Because you can't predict when the OS decides to run your thread. (You'll also get unpredictable timings on *the same computer* sometimes.)

Comment: @immibis You are always using threads, because every Java app is multi-threaded (and the OS has multitasking)...

Comment: @lbalazscs Using threads *in your code* then. And you know what I meant.

Comment: Ok, if you look at my code, I have been using Threads. And so far, nothing unpredictable has happened.

Comment: @SuperstarGamer can you predict exactly how far your pikachu moves up if I hold the up key for three seconds?

Comment: @immibis Yes, I will do that in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would commonly see either [delta-timing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8289341/4455716) or [fixed-timestep](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) implemented into the game loop.

Delta timing uses a `delta` variable based on measuring the time between each frame. You would multiply all transformations by `delta` to make the game run at the same speed on multiple computers. This is smooth and easy to implement, but you have to remember to multiply **all** transformations by `delta`.

Fixed time-stepping, on the other hand, somehow controls the time between the frames, eliminating the need for a delta variable. It is known to be slightly choppy / difficult to implement, but you no longer need to apply `delta` everywhere.

While you could implement it yourself, it would be easier switching over to an actual game library like LibGDX or Slick2D, where they handle it (and *much* more) for you.

Also, unstable performance may also be caused by using so many threads. The movement could be done in a much cleaner way while updating in a basic game loop;

```
if(Main.KeysPressed.contains(Main.LEFT + ""))
    Main.setPikachuPosition(Main.getPikaX() - 1, Main.getPikaY());
```

Comment: Alright, Ill look into Delta timing, I remember using this in Slick2D API, but its been so long, I forgot about it! Thanks! Ill set this as the answer when I look it up :)