# How do I delay one image from showing on the screen in Java?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm so far working on a Pacman game for my grade 12 computer science.

I want to allow the monsters to automatically move around the game. I'm using Slick2D and LWJGL for my game. I have this bit of code in my game that controls where the blue monster is moving.

```
if (bluePosX < 400) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bluePosX++;
}
```

So basically what I see on the screen is the blue monster automatically moving towards the right direction. My only problem is when I use `Thread.sleep(100);` it delays the entire screen. I just want to delay how long the blue monster should wait before moving in the right direction. How do I only delay the blue monster image and not the entire screen?

Comment: Either one thread per monster, or a Priority Queue of actor updates (where "actor" is something that can move on-screen) ordered by deadline, where you can set the deadline for each update action sometime in the future.  Probably the second option.  Another strong argument for "separation of concerns" as I commented on an earlier question.

Comment: Welcome to the world of "peeling the onion", i.e. finding out things have many more layers and are more complex than you thought when you started.  I applaud your determination in tackling such a large project for a high-school class.  Good luck.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thank you for the comment! What if I used Java Swing Timer? Would that work?

Comment: _...Java Swing Timer?"_ - that's out of my area of expertise (more of a backend/DB guy myself).  Experiment....

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you set how often the game loop updates, e.g. 60 times a second = 60fps. In that case 100ms is equal to 6 updates (each update being spaced 1000/60 ms apart). So just wait 6 updates before changing `bluePosX++`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to work with the delta you have in your update method.

See: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282501/how-do-i-work-with-delta-in-slick2d-lwjgl-or-game-programming-in-general)

You can count the delta up in a variable and execute a certain action after the maximum delta is reached. After that you can reset the deltaCounter to 0. I wouldn't recommend using Thread.sleep or anything similiar. You could use Java Swing Timer but usually timing related things are achieved by using the delta. It's easier and provided by the engine you use.